# Angular / Typescript: pass a generic type T as an argument in ComponentType<T>

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, overlay, typeof

I'm trying to create an Overlay (Angular CDK) service that has generic methods to receive different kinds of components. This is just so I can avoid having a separate service for every component that'll be displayed in an overlay, specially because they're all pretty much the same, with the exception of the injectors.

In its barest form, it should be something like this:

```
createOverlay<T extends Component>() : void
{
  const portal = new ComponentPortal(T);
}
```

But I get a "'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here." error, even though the ComponentPortal constructor does expect a type.

I could pass the component that'll be calling the createOverlay() method as an argument, I suppose, but, as you'll see, I clearly have no idea as how to get the type said argument:

```
createOverlay(component: Component) : void
{
  const overlayRef = this.overlay.create();
  const portal = new ComponentPortal(typeof component);
}
```

I'll appreciate your corrections and suggestions.

Any ideas?

---

The ComponentPortal constructor:

```
constructor(component: ComponentType<T>, viewContainerRef?: ViewContainerRef | null, injector?: Injector | null, componentFactoryResolver?: ComponentFactoryResolver | null);
```

---

ComponentType is actually an interface:

```
export interface ComponentType<T> {
    new (...args: any[]): T;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the `ComponentPortal` constructor's signature?

Comment: I added it to the original post as an edit.

Comment: Great. Please not that there is no such thing as passing a type as a value. Types and interfaces are shapes that values can assume. You can do some operations with them such as type unions, extends and etc, but you can't pass them as an argument to methods or functions. Anyway: please not that the component that the constructor takes is of type `ComponentType<T>`, which is a class. You have to create a class that extends `ComponentType`, instantiate it and pass the instance as an argument to the `ComponentPortal` constructor.

Comment: ComponentType<T> is an interface, to make matters more complicated. The only thing within it is a method that, I presume, will instantiate whatever class of type T you assign it. I added it to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a component, so use `Type<any>`.

```
 createOverlay(component: Type<any>): void
```

Import it from  `import {Type} from "@angular/core";`